# Significance of the Wizard of Oz references

Tags: analysis, fairly-legal

The show [*Fairly Legal*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1586676/) employs some references to *The Wizard of Oz* (also note the usage of *"The Yellow Brick Road Song"* as theme song), in particular *Kate* using different roles as knicknames on her cell phone for the people in her life:

- *The Wicked Witch* - for her boss and stepmother *Lauren*, whom she doesn't like for probably both those aspects, but who isn't as evil as *Kate* thinks her to be.
- *The Lion* - for her assistant *Leonardo* (*"Leo"*), who is kind of "nerdy" and sometimes helps *Kate* steer clear of her chaos.
- *The Tin-Man* - for her husband *Justin*, which she is separated from yet seems to have an on-and-off relationship with.
- *The Wizard* - for her late father, with whom she has somehow different views of the law in practice.
- And I'd just infer *Kate*, who indeed seems a bit lost at times, to be *Dorothy* then.

(Did I maybe forget anyone here? Strangely enough her brother doesn't seem to have knickname.)

But having only superficial knowledge about *The Wizard of Oz*, I'm not sure if to make anything more out of those references than a mere side joke. **Do these references have any deeper meaning?** Do those *Wizard of Oz* characters and their roles in the story maybe provide a description of the corresponding *Fairly Legal* characters or at least how *Kate* sees them?

Answer (score 2):

The references are not "side jokes" but metaphors on Kate's view of them.

*The Wicked Witch* opposes.
*The Lion* helps without confronting.
*The Tin-Man* wants to understand but confuses his options.
*The Wizard* sees all and knows all from his perspective which is different than the perspective of Kate.

Comment: *"The Tin-Man wants to understand but confuses his options."* - I guess I need some help with this one.

Comment: In the Wizard of Oz, the Tin-Man wants a heart but already has one. I interpreted that as questioning his decisions/motives and thus insecure in choices.